# Show algebraically that this function $f(n)$ is not one-to-one

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

I want to show algebraically that this function is not a one-to-one function

> The function $f: \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ defined by $$f(n) = \begin{cases}
>  \frac{n}{2}&\text{if}\, n \text{ is even}\\
>  \frac{n+1}{2}&\text{if}\, n \text { is odd}\\
> \end{cases}$$

I know the function is not one-to-one because $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=0$, but how do I use $f(x)=f(y)\Longrightarrow x=y.$ to show that it is not a one-to-one function.

When I try, I do the following:

Case when $n$ is even:
$$\frac{n_1}{2} = \frac{n_2}{2}$$
$$n_1 = n_2 $$

Case when $n$ is odd:
$$\frac{n_1 +1}{2}= \frac{n_2 +1}{2}$$
$$ n_1 = n_2$$

This is wrong, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: First of all $f(1)=(1+1)/2=1$.

Comment: I don‘t understand, you noting $f(0) = f(1) = 0$ already proves that the function is not injective.

Comment: You've shown that it's 1-1 when restricted to odd integers and when restricted to even integers, but as your comment suggests neither of these is the problem case...

Comment: why is it not the case that it is restricted to just either or odd?

Comment: You are trying to contradict the fact that if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$. So let's pick $x = 1$ and $y=2$. We get $f(x) = 1$ and $f(y) = 1$ where we have $f(x) = f(y)$ but $x \neq y$.

Comment: @Kezer I want to know how to do these problems when the answer isn't very obvious

Comment: @Sam There is no general way, other than finding two elements of the domain that map to the same value. Unless, you have some additional information on the structure of the objects you are mapping (i.e., homomorphisms between groups, etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Expanding on @user113102's comment a little for you: you've established that if you take two even values of $n$ then you have injectivity, and if you take two odd values of $n$ you have injectivity.  So what's left to look at is: are there any cases where the values $f(n)$ assumes are equal for an odd and an even value of $n$?  In this case, that means, can we solve
$$ \frac{n_1}{2} = \frac{n_2+1}{2}?$$

So, multiplying both sides by $2$ tells us that if we can, we have
$$n_1 = n_2+1$$
As you've already seen $n_1=2 \Rightarrow n_2=1$ solves it, but now you can also see there is a whole family of solutions.  Take $n_1=1081$ and we see that if $n_2=1080$ we have $f(n_1)=f(n_2)$.